# I get an undefined method `link_to_add_association' for #<#<Class:0x00007fb9a1cc4f68>:0x00007fb9a1fdf658> when using the gem "cocoon"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a nested form with the gem cocoon and I am following this (https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/nested-forms-with-cocoon) tutorial as it's almost identical to what I intend to do. In short I want to create a form where a user can create a list and then add as many items as he/she wishes to that list.

However, I get an undefined method `link_to_add_association' for #<#:0x00007fb9a1fdf658>.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqpYn.png)

**Models**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
has_many :lists, dependent: :destroy
end

class List < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: 
proc { |att| att['description'].blank?}
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :list, optional: true
end
```

**Views**
**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for (@list) do |f|  %>
 <%= f.error_notification  %>
 <div class= "form-inputs"> 
  <%= f.input :name %>
 </div>
 <h3>Items</h3>
 <table class= "table"> 
  <thead> 
   <tr> 
    <th></th>
    <th>Item Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody class="items"> 
  <%= simple_fields_for :items do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'item_fields', f: builder %>
  <%end %>
 </tbody>
 </table>

<div class= "form-actions"> 
 <%= f.button :submit %>
 <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Item', f, :items, class: 'btn btn- 
 primary', data: {association_insertion_node: '.items', 
 association_insertion_method: :append } %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**_item_fields.html.erb**

```
<tr class= "nested-fields"> 
 <td> 
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove item", f, class: 'btn btn- 
  primary btn-xs' %>
 </td>
 <td> <%= f.input :name, label: false %></td>
 <td> <%= f.input :description, label: false %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Did you restart the Rails application after adding the `cocoon` gem?

Comment: Do you mean killing the server and restarting?

Comment: Correct, i looked at the gem and it doesn't appear that they've changed anything around this. Maybe also try running `spring stop`

Comment: Thanks I will! One more question: could you elaborate what function the _todolist.json.jbuilder serves? I saw those files in the source code but they are not covered in the video tutorial on cocoon.

Comment: Killing the server and restarting it helped to resolve this issue. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to refer to the parent model.
change this

`<%= simple_fields_for :items do |builder| %>`

by this

`<%= f.simple_fields_for :items do |builder| %>`

The problem was in the application.js file, 
cocoon must be loaded after jQuery.

`//= require jquery3
//= require rails-ujs
//= require cocoon`

Comment: Thanks so much, that helped a lot! But for some reason the form now doesn't render the input fields from the "item partial". Any idea? @kobaltz

Comment: make sure to build an item object in the new action list controller
# list controller
`def new
  @list = List.new items: [Item.new]
end`

Comment: Again that helped a lot :D thanks! But now I have only one item row. When I click on "Add Item" (see code above) or "remove item" it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Hi Luis Silva, thanks for you re incredible help! I have one more question though. I can now add one item, but then the second item row doesnt appear automatically. I am bit puzzled because I have followed the tutorial by the letter. Would you mind taking a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421811/problems-with-cocoon-gem-nothing-happens-when-i-want-to-add-or-remove-nested-el

Comment: Hi Emanuel, I can't find what the problem is, but here one thing that you should to consider.
your partial must be named `_item_fields.html.erb`, because in your second post I'm seen it as `_item.html.erb`

also if you want you can upload your project to github or bitbucket and I can try to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you give me your Github name so I can give you access?

Comment: Alright! It's on Github and I make you a contributor just in case :)

Comment: Hi Luis Silva, since you seem to solve my problems in no time I have another question for you :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518946/implementing-searchkick-and-typeahead-in-my-rails-app-doesnt-work.