# implementing searchkick and typeahead in my rails app doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have tried to implement searchkick and typeahead.js in my app by following this tutorial https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/searchkick-and-elasticsearch#show_notes but somehow it doesn't work properly. The typeahead doesnt work at all and the search works if I type the entire name "lito" but doesn't return the user if I just type "li".[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJwCX.png)  [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUmcf.png)  One noticeable difference from the tutorial is that I didn't save the typeahead bundle in vendor/assets since that folder doesn't exit in my rails app but through the command `yarn add typeahead` and then in javascript/application.js I did: ìmport typeahead``
If you need any other parts of the code let me know . Thanks in advance :)

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

def index
search = params[:term].present? ? params[:term] : nil
@users = if search
 User.search(search)
else
  User.all
end
end

def autocomplete
render json: User.search(params[:query], {
  fields: ["first_name", "last_name", "username"],
  match: :word_start,
  limit: 10,
  load: false,
  misspellings: {below: 5}
}).map(&:username)
end

def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def profile
@my_lists = current_user.lists
end

private
def set_user
end

def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username)
end
end
```

**Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
searchkick
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
has_many :lists, dependent: :destroy

def search_data
{
  username: username,
  first_name: first_name,
  last_name: last_name
}
end
end
```

**Users.js**

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
var users = new Bloodhound({
datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
remote: {
  url: '/profiles/autocomplete?query=%QUERY',
  wildcard: '%QUERY'
}
});
$('#users_search').typeahead(null, {
source: users
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify the fields that use word_start in your model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick word_start: [:first_name, :last_name, :username]
end
```

Then reindex. https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#instant-search--autocomplete

Comment: Thanks for looking at it! I added it but it doesnt solve the problem. There are several things that are off. For example if I type in console search("li") I get three results but in my view I only get one.  Here's the repo if you want to take a look at it https://github.com/litodertechie/rails_listy